Azure DevOps - pipeline build fails due to timeout and local VS builds are suceeding
When I run builds on xUnit tests in my VS all my Tests are passing but on pipeline build I get only 1 error and that is due to timeout.
This is code error from DevOps:

Error Message:
2024-07-03T13:46:54.0677410Z    System.Exception : Assertions not tested due to timeout

VS Build

DevOps error:

Tried Re-queueing build but always same thing, maybe DevOps has different timeout than VS?
this is log downloaded from DevOps:
2024-07-03T13:46:25.7473431Z Starting test execution, please wait...
2024-07-03T13:46:25.9228679Z A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
2024-07-03T13:46:52.8484605Z [xUnit.net 00:00:17.95]     MeltFieldTest.PlantUnitTest.ShouldDetectAndCancelPlantUnitEventMultipleTimes(fieldEventName: "HotMetalCarEmptyFieldEvent", antagonistFieldEventName: "LadleOnHotMetalCarFieldEvent", stateName: "HotMetalCar", initialValue: 2, finalValue: 1, plantUnitEventType: "HotMetalCarEmptyPlantUnitEvent", candidateTime: 1) [FAIL]
2024-07-03T13:46:54.0672440Z   Failed MeltFieldTest.PlantUnitTest.ShouldDetectAndCancelPlantUnitEventMultipleTimes(fieldEventName: "HotMetalCarEmptyFieldEvent", antagonistFieldEventName: "LadleOnHotMetalCarFieldEvent", stateName: "HotMetalCar", initialValue: 2, finalValue: 1, plantUnitEventType: "HotMetalCarEmptyPlantUnitEvent", candidateTime: 1) [2 s]
2024-07-03T13:46:54.0677109Z   Error Message:
2024-07-03T13:46:54.0677410Z    System.Exception : Assertions not tested due to timeout
2024-07-03T13:46:54.0677596Z   Stack Trace:
2024-07-03T13:46:54.0677874Z      at MeltFieldTest.Utils.Poller.CheckUntil(Action[] assertions) in D:\a\1\s\MeltField\MeltFieldTest\Utils\Poller.cs:line 28
2024-07-03T13:46:54.0678450Z    at MeltFieldTest.PlantUnitTest.ShouldDetectAndCancelPlantUnitEventMultipleTimes(String fieldEventName, String antagonistFieldEventName, String stateName, Int32 initialValue, Int32 finalValue, String plantUnitEventType, Int32 candidateTime) in D:\a\1\s\MeltField\MeltFieldTest\PlantUnitTest.cs:line 171
2024-07-03T13:48:21.9539867Z Results File: D:\a\_temp\VssAdministrator_fv-az285-59_2024-07-03_13_46_50.trx
2024-07-03T13:48:21.9543780Z 
2024-07-03T13:48:21.9592259Z Failed!  - Failed:     1, Passed:   207, Skipped:     0, Total:   208, Duration: 1 m 31 s - MeltFieldTest.dll (net6.0)
2024-07-03T13:48:23.3368206Z Test run for D:\a\1\s\MeltProduction\MeltProductionTest\bin\Debug\net6.0\MeltProductionTest.dll (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)
2024-07-03T13:48:23.4091901Z Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 17.10.0 (x64)
2024-07-03T13:48:23.4121303Z Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Yaml -
trigger:
  enabled: false
variables:
- name: buildConfiguration
  value: 'Debug'
stages:
- stage: __default
  jobs:
  - job: Job
    pool:
      vmImage: windows-2022
    steps:
    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: "Display build info"
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          echo 'branchName="$(Build.SourceBranchName)"'
          echo 'buildNumber="$(Build.BuildNumber)"'
          echo 'listing content of $(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
          ls -R ./
        workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: "Restore Nuget Packages"
      inputs:
        command: 'restore'
        projects: '**/*ForPipelines.sln'
        feedsToUse: 'config'
        nugetConfigPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/NuGet.config'
        verbosityRestore: 'Normal'
    - task: VSBuild@1
      inputs:
        solution: '**\*ForPipelines.sln'
        platform: 'Any CPU'
        configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
        msbuildArgs: '/p:RunWixToolsOutOfProc=true'
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: "Run Tests"
      inputs:
        command: 'test'
        projects: '**/*ForPipelines.sln'
        arguments: /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutput=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\TestCoverageResults\ /p:MergeWith=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\TestCoverageResults\coverage.json /p:CoverletOutputFormat="cobertura%2cjson" -m:1 --no-build
        publishTestResults: true
    - task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
      displayName: 'Publish Code Coverage Results'
      inputs:
        codeCoverageTool: 'Cobertura'
        summaryFileLocation: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\TestCoverageResults\coverage.cobertura.xml



It's recommended to share the pipeline definition(yaml or task details).  Are  you using Microsoft-hosted agent or  self-hosted agent? What does the test MeltFieldTest.PlantUnitTest.ShouldDetectAndCancelPlantUnitEventMultipleTimes do? If it tries to access local resource(network, VM, database...etc), you could need to set up self-hosted agent for connection.

Thanks for the update.  As per the comment  I run this test 18 times(with different inline data) and 17 of them pass and only 1 is failing due to timeout, may i know when it's failed, if you re-run the failed job, will it succeed?

Double-check if there is a timeout set at the task or job level and adjust it accordingly.
Example:
jobs:
  - job: Build
    timeoutInMinutes: 20 # <------------------- job timeout
    steps:
      # other tasks here ...
      - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
        displayName: Run unit tests
        timeoutInMinutes: 10 # <------------------- task timeout
        inputs:
          command: test
          projects: '**/*Tests/*.csproj'
          arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'

See Jobs timeouts for more details regarding default and maximum timeout values.

no timeouts are set in yaml

@MarkoGrbeš, can you share the yaml or task details? What does the test do? I also added the comment above.

@MarkoGrbeš a bit more context and details would be extremely useful, as already mentioned by wadezhou-MSFT. Otherwise we can only speculate about the issue.

@wadezhou-MSFT I added yaml on top, sorry for formatting I'm a bit new to stack overflow as of asking questions, problem is that doesn't get to my heat I run this test 18 times(with different inline data) and 17 of them pass and only 1 is failing due to timeout?

@MarkoGrbeš the problem might be in the test or maybe it's a connectivity issue. Please edit your question and explain what does the failing test do.

Assuming that your test accesses a database it could be:

Locally it runs fine since the test has access to the database server.

When the test runs on the server, it cannot access the database, so the connection waits for a timeout. Before the database connection times out, the test execution times out.


